# Is there a proof that tax lot optimizer is really optimal?

Tags: united-states, capital-gains-tax

Sites like TD Ameritrade offer a specific lot method of recording capital gains that claims to be most efficient. Such as using the following order:

> Short-term loss– descending order by cost per share (highest to
> lowest), and as a result, taking the biggest short-term losses first
>
> Long-term loss– descending order by cost per share
>
> Long-term gain– descending order by cost per share (highest to
> lowest), and as a result, taking the smallest long-term gain first
>
> Short-term gain– descending order by cost per share

https://www.tdameritrade.com/education/taxes/what-is-a-tax-lot.page

I'd like to know if there is a proof anywhere that this is indeed the optimal algorithm. Note that I'm aware there are special tax situations that might make it non optimal by including say carryovers etc or wanting to use the $3000 annual allowance etc. but those aren't my concern here. I'm only interested in the algorithm that maximizes the amount of long term capital gains when splitting the overall capital gains into long term and short term, given only the list of buys and sells and no other information.

Comment: In the US, in non-retirement accounts, if you have to take a gain, a long term gain is the only one with a potential tax rate.  If given the option you would always take a long term gain over a short term gain.  So if TD says that’s what it’s doing, great.  Maybe ask TD for proof otherwise I don’t see a question in your question.

Comment: @quid My concern is that the algorithm as it stands may use up some purchases in the early steps e.g. to realize short term losses, which may have more value if saved for use until later in the algorithm e.g. to realize long term gains.

Comment: Well, I agree, TDs tax optimizing engine probably can’t predict the future and uses the data at the time of a trade to determine what lots to sell, and which might prove to be non-optimal in the future.

Comment: @quid I'm looking for the optimal algorithm when assigning lots after all the trades are known

Comment: You don't get to assign lots after all the trades are known unless all trades are executed on the same day.  You assign lots at the time of the trade and the tax period spans an entire year.

Comment: @quid yes, that's what I've read about stocks. My understanding is that it is still possible to do this with crypto, which inspires my question

Comment: Taxation has between very little and nothing to do with the specific instrument.  The same way you can't avoid income taxes because your employer paid you in bitcoin rather than dollars.  Though, like most things, this would only matter in an audit.

Comment: @quid While I think that's generally true, see questions 39 and 40 here for rules on crypto taxation, which seem to differ for the rules on stock taxation by saying nothing about having to identify lots at the time of trade https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/frequently-asked-questions-on-virtual-currency-transactions

Comment: I would disagree with your read of those two answers, and question/answer 41 indicates chronological FIFO if you can't or don't specify your lots specifically.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

There is no proof that it's optimal, because it's not optimal.

Suppose that the current date is December 16. There's a stock whose last trade price is $100, and you have the following tax lots:

- 100 shares purchased at $50.01 on January 1
- 100 shares purchased at $50 on December 1

Then suppose you want to sell 100 shares. TD Ameritrade's algorithm will see that these are all short-term gains, and so it will sell the lot with the highest purchase price: the shares purchased at $50.01 on January 1.

However, given that you want as much as possible of your realized gains to be long-term gains, it's probably better to sell the shares that you bought on December 1. That way, your remaining short-term unrealized gains will turn into long-term unrealized gains much sooner.

Answer (score 0):

Their engine is the same steps that you would use if you had all your trades in a spreadsheet and knew that you needed to sell 172 shares today.

Remember that is only one of the [methods they provide/allow](https://www.tdameritrade.com/education/taxes/what-is-a-tax-lot.page):

- FIFO (first-in, first-out)
- LIFO (last-in, first-out)
- Highest cost
- Lowest cost
- Specific lot
- Tax efficient loss harvester
- Average cost

The section you quoted has to do with long positions, they have a slightly different approach for short positions.

They also have an important note:

> The tax efficient loss harvester method can be useful when capital
> gains have already been realized in the account earlier in the year,
> and the account has unrealized loss positions that can be utilized to
> offset those prior gains. Please note: This method does not factor in
> the possibility that a lot sold via this method will cause a wash
> sale, and therefore disallow the loss on the trade.

It doesn't know the future. It doesn't know what you have done or will do the rest of the year. They just have some software that will do the math for you.